# What is the difference between getChildHtml and getBlockHtml

Tags: magento-1.8, template, blocks, layout, static-block

### Synopsis

- What is the difference between `getChildHtml` and `getBlockHtml`?
- How can I get the cms/block title in the template?

I have essentially replaced the footer with my own footer and set my own `<?= $this->getChildHtml('...') ?>` This didn't work until I used: `<?= $this->getBlockHtml('...') ?>`.

#### Layout XML:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <block type="core/template" name="custom_footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="cms/block" name="child_1">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_child_1</block_id></action>
            </block>
         </block>
    </layout>
</default>
```

#### Template (doesn't work):

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sp4"><?= $this->getChildHtml('child_1') ?></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

#### Template (Works):

```
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sp4"><?= $this->getBlockHtml('child_1') ?></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

---

### Solution:

First of all I had to override the footer inside my `local.xml` by:

```
<default>
    <block type="core/template" template="page/html/custom_footer.phtml" name ="custom_footer" as "footer" />
</default>
```

The I had to add my children (in order for `getChildHtml()` to work):

```
<reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="child_1">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_child_1</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`getBlockHtml('block_name_here')` get's you the html of the block with name `block_name_here` if it finds it in the layout...anywhere.
`getChildHtml('block_name_here')` get's you the html of the block with name `block_name_here` only if that block is a child of the current block.

Here is an example. Consider the next layout section

```
<block type="core/template" template="some_template.phtml" name="some_name" />
<block type="core/template" template="some_other_template.phtml" name="some_other_name" />
```

Now in the template file `some_template.phtml` if you add this line of code `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('some_other_name')?>` you will get the html for the block `some_other_name`.
If you add `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('some_other_name')?>` you will get nothing.

IN the following scenario

```
<block type="core/template" template="some_template.phtml" name="some_name">
    <block type="core/template" template="some_other_template.phtml" name="some_other_name" />
</block>
```

`getChildHtml` and `getBlockHtml` will get you the same thing. the html of the block `some_other_name`.

Comment: Thanks - So am I right in thinking that in my updated question that: `<block type="cms/block" name="child_1">` is a child of the `footer` block?  In which case why does `getChildHtml('child_1') not work?

Comment: @Ash. I think in your case that `getChildHtml` does not work because the layout page (3columns.phtml for example) still renders the default footer block.I mean it has `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>` inside it. Am I right? I'm shooting in the dark here because I don't know how your layout page looks like, but this is the first thing I would check.  Try changing it to `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_footer') ?>` and see if you can use `getChildHtml`.

Comment: I think you're right; I overwrote the old footer block it was working - Although the actual problem was not Magento related.  Your answer clears my assumptions - thanks d00d :)